# Running npm ls <package name> after npm update doesnt show updated version?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-update

i have done the following steps.
1- npm install

2- npm ls c - this gave me dependency tree showing a particular version of package c say 1.4.1

```
└─┬ a@1.4.0
  └─┬ b@0.13.0
    └── c@1.4.1
```

3- npm update c --depth=100
c@1.4.8
added 1 package from 1 contributor, updated 3 packages and audited 69 packages in 2.112s
found 3 low severity vulnerabilities
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details 
4- npm ls c

```
└─┬ a@1.4.0
  └─┬ b@0.13.0
    └── c@1.4.1
```

This still showing old package, but when i verified in node_modules i see version 1.4.8.
What can i do to make npm ls report updated dependency tree?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i inadvertently left package-lock.json, after removing package-lock.json and running npm ls gave the correct dependency tree.